# Azure DevOps: Get contributors for Git repositories

Tags: azure-devops

I'm searching for a way to get the list of contributors to each of the repositories in Azure DevOps Git.

The REST API documents how to get the list of repositories, among others: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

I can't find a way to get info about the actual users of the repositories, i.e. commiters/contributors.

Ideally I would want exactly what GitHub offers in this API endpoint, where I input the repository I am interested in and get a list of contributors and the amount of contributions each made: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-repository-contributors

If the REST API doesn't offer this, is there another way I can retrieve this info?

Comment: Clone the repositories. (If that's not the answer you want, take off the [tag:git] tag...)

Answer (score 1):

**Command line:**

1. Unfetched remote branches: Make sure that you have fetched all
   remote branches to your local repository. To do this, use the
   command:

   `git fetch --all`
2. After fetching all remote branches, run the git log command again:

   `git log --all --format='%aN <%aE>' | sort -u`
3. Output should like this:

   ```
   Name, User <user.name@email.com>
   Title, Dev <dev.title@email.com>
   Master, Git <git.master@email.com>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> Azure DevOps: Get contributors for Git repositories

You could use the REST API [Groups - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to list the ID of the contributors group:

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

[image]

Then use the REST API [Members - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)：

```
GET https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/GroupEntitlements/{groupId}/members?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

[image]

Comment: Would this list contributors to the project in general or to the specific repository that interests me? I'd like to be able to get info about actual committers, not just an "assumption" via group or project membership

Comment: @Charles, list contributors to the project Not repo. There is no such contributors to the repo.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there is no way to get repository contributors/commiters via the REST API - correct?

Comment: @Charles, Not accurate, there is no such repository contributors, so that we could not get it instead of it being there, we can’t get it.